# Why does Rashi put Yackov before Eisuhv?

Tags: parashat-toldot

B"H

In the beginning of parshas Toldos, it says "these are the descendants of Yitzchak", then seemingly begins to talk about some events that happened to Yitzhak himself, but doesn't immediately say his descendants.

To this Rashi says,

"And these are the generations of Isaac the son of Abraham: [תּוֹלְדוֹת refers to] Jacob and Esau mentioned in this section.

ואלה תולדות יצחק: יעקב ועשיו האמורים בפרשה:"

The question:

Why does Rashi mention Yackov before Eisuhv, considering Eisuhv is the firstborn, and the first one mentioned in the parsha?

Comment: Yaakov is more important.

Comment: Maybe because in this parasha we learn that Yaacov is the real first born!

Comment: @rabbi interesting